# Match a string prefix in PHP

Tags: php, validation

I have a username of the format, say: "mySite", with a number suffixed to it.

I need to check whether the entered username matches that format.

I match strings using preg_match as follows:

```
if(!(preg_match("/^[mySite]([0-9])+$/", $loginName)))

    echo "Error";
```

But, I don't get the desired results.

Is the above expression correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. try

```
preg_match('/^mySite\d+$/', $loginName)
```

`[mySite]` will match any of the letters m,y,S,i,t,e. and only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if(!(preg_match("/^mySite([0-9])+$/", $loginName)))

    echo "Error";
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets around `mySite`. Otherwise you're just matching a single character with it that is either `m`, `y`, `S`, `i`, `t` or `e`.